# FastAPI: CORS Middleware not working with GET method

Tags: fastapi

I try to use CORS on the FastAPi framework but it dose not working with GET method

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/test1")
async def test1():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Comment: what output did you get from that specific route?

Comment: @l.b.vasoya
Here is the response header:
 content-length: 25 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Tue,08 Dec 2020 08:02:07 GMT 
 server: uvicorn

Comment: I think you have to mention which method is you want to allow you need to specify all method except `get` in `allow_methods=["*"]`  like `allow_methods=["POST","PUT","DELETE"],` etc

Comment: my question is CROS is working fine with all method except GET ...
so why i should except it .?
@l.b.vasoya

Comment: Please include the request/response headers and the error message if there are any.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032415/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and the solution is to not use `add_middelware` but do the following:

First import from Starlette:

```
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
```

Create the middleware:

```
middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=['*'],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*']
    )
]
```

and then:

```
app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)
```

This should work

Comment: Honestly, not working for me!

Comment: Yeap, works for me too. For some reason that `add_middleware` method does not work.

Answer (score 10):

When testing, make sure you add `Origin` header to your request. Otherwise `CORSMiddleware` **will not** send back the cors headers.

It may not be clear at first, but it is written [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#simple-requests) in the documentation:

> Simple requests
>
> Any request with an `Origin` header. In this case the middleware will
> pass the request through as normal, but will include appropriate CORS
> headers on the response.

So any request **without** an `Origin` will be ignored by `CORSMiddleware` and no CORS headers will be added.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Sam_Ste, I had the same problem! I set my imports back to FastAPI and it still works. I think they are just proxies for the starlette modules (IMHO). The method is the vital thing, not using app_middleware.

```
from fastapi.middleware import Middleware
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the above mentioned ideas worked. I had to create a custom middleware like this.

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def cors_handler(request: Request, call_next):
    response: Response = await call_next(request)
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = os.environ.get('allowedOrigins')
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    return response
```