# How can I enable CORS in FastAPI?

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

I'm trying to enable CORS in this very basic FastAPI example, however it doesn't seem to be working.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*']
)

@app.get('/')
def read_main():
    return {'message': 'Hello World!'}
```

This is the response I get:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 19:27:37 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 26
< content-type: application/json
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"message":"Hello World!"}*
```

Comment: It seems to be working. You are allowing requests from every origin

Comment: @Isabi I don't get _Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *_ in my response though.

Comment: Have you tried with a browser or an app? My guess is that curl is not sending the `Origin` in the headers because it has no well defined origin, so it cannot return it in the headers

Comment: I tried with Chrome and Postman. The only headers I get in the response are: _content-length_, _content-type_, _date_ and _server_.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried with the full example? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=+cors#use-corsmiddleware

Comment: I have tried that too. I've no idea what's going on unfortunately...

Comment: I tested the sample code of the official docs and it does not show the CORS when requested from the terminal, but it shows them from javascript running within the browser (Chromium `Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`)

Comment: If CORS is indeed enabled, should the _Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *_ header not be sent with the response?

Comment: If it's in the browser in which `CORS` permissions are mandatory yes, but in the case of an API requests from different sources/domains will be performed, then no. `CORS` are mainly for security reasons (scripts that perform requests to external resources)

Comment: @lsabi of what use is this CORS if it cant restrict at all times? looks to me like a useless feature as it can be bypassed pretty easily and just does not work, also if behind web server proxy...wont work except if proxy is setup to use CORS also

Comment: @uberrebu I don't understand your question. Goal of CORS is to support direct access of javascript to third party APIs

Comment: or to restrict and only allow from certain origins/domains...yes or no?

Comment: @lsabi yes or no? CORS is to control access to endpoint based on origin/domain? yes or no?

Comment: @uberrebu No, CORS is for restricting access to the same domain. I want to be the only one accessing my API from the browser, thus I allow only my domain as origin (though direct API calls, not through browser, are allowed). This ensures more security for my users who navigate via browser

Comment: you said No and then agree with what am saying, contradicting there...you just said for restricting access...so if this CORS can be bypassed, then is that security of illusion of security?

Comment: as here is written: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191061/fastapi-cors-middleware-not-working-with-get-method?rq=3 The reponse is only generated if the sender includes origin in the header.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

you can find answer from this:[fastapi cors](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=%20cors#use-corsmiddleware)

then this is a very simple code to achieve it:

1. create a python file and named it `main.py`.
2. add code in this file.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

and run this app:

```sh
uvicorn main:app  --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

if you computer ip is 192.12.12.12

you can check this link and just write a small javascript in html:

```
<script>
        fetch("http://192.12.12.12:8000/").then((Response) => {
            return Response.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: not working for me even restarted the server

Comment: @SunilGarg it shouldn't work. on the link given by yuanzz https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=%20cors#use-corsmiddleware, it literally says "allow_origins cannot be set to ['*'] for credentials to be allowed"

Comment: You can't use [*] as allowed origins while with_credentials is set to true

Comment: Literal quote from the help page: *"Also, allow_origins cannot be set to `[*]` for credentials to be allowed, origins must be specified."*

Comment: This solution is great

Comment: As others have said REMOVE `allow_methods=["*"],` if the origin is a wildcard otherwise it WILL NOT WORK

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#wildcards), it is preferabe to explicitly specify the allowed origins, e.g., `origins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000']`, instead of using the `"*"` wildcard, which would allow **any** origin at the cost of excluding everything that involves credentials from the communication, such as cookies and Authorization headers. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738) as well.

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer was invaluable and it helped us to get our demo ready !

Comment: The docs explicitly say: allow_credentials - Indicate that cookies should be supported for cross-origin requests. Defaults to False. Also, allow_origins cannot be set to ['*'] for credentials to be allowed, origins must be specified. I know FastAPI will quietly accept * origin and allow_credentials=True, but it will most likely not pass cookies.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, CORS not works when pydantic or type problems occured.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# works well!
@app.get("/list")
async def main():
    return ["hi", "hello"]

# error cases
from typing import List
from app.nosql.model import Book

@app.get("/error")
async def main():
    # case 1
    ret = mongo_db.engine.find(Book, limit=10) # keyword "await" missing
    return ret  # CORS 500 error
    # case 2
    ret: List[Book] = await mongo_db.engine.find(Book, limit=10) # data was not fit with model Book
    return ret # CORS error
    # case 3
    return ["hi", "hello"] # works well...
```

Whats the server-side error says?
It might be error occurs in server.
How about test with new function. (has no error)
If server works well.. humm.. sry about that.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's better to add comments instead of answers if you've got a similar question. But even then this isn't a minimal working example. So it's not clear what you're trying to add to the conversation here.

Comment: CORS headers are **not** added when the request ends in an error. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407352/17865804) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and just found the solution. Using lots of copypasted code, I was spinning up another FastAPI instance somewhere where CORS was not configured, like this:

```
app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*']
)

... much later somewhere within lots of green code ...
app = FastAPI()
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding expose_headers helped me to fix this

```
expose_headers=["*"]
```

Comment: Where? As an argument to `add_middleware()`?

Comment: Yes, just like this: 

`app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    ...,
expose_headers=["*"]
)
`
Also, you can be very specific about the headers you want to allow to avoid security risks!

Answer (score 0):

If the (browser) client makes a request from a local file (e.g. file://.../main.html), we run into an edge case. The request origin must then be specified as `'null'`, when requesting with credentials included.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware, Response

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['null'],
    allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=['*'], allow_headers=['*'])

@app.get('/')
def main():
    return Response('OK', status_code=200)
```

You can see the origin of the request in the error message of the browser console, if running a chromium-based browser. In Firefox however, the origin is hidden.

Please note that this has **security implications**, and it is thus **not recommended**. See this related answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78006792/23263766.