# Unable to access FastAPI application through devices on Local Network

Tags: api, networking, cors, fastapi

The problem seems extremely simple; I just want my FastAPI server to accept requests from my phone and my emulator. However, it does not.

1. Note that I have no network problems. I have my node server on this same computer, and I can freely send requests to it and get a response.

I can send requests from my browser, and postman. No problem with that.

```
from enum import Enum
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "https://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://myPhoneIp",
    "https://myPhoneIp:8080",
    "http://emulatorIp",
    "https://emulatorIp",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=False,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    print('someone sent a request')
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Why is this small piece of code not working? I am not using any cookies, etc. So I set `allow_credentials=False`, and even if I set it to `True`, it is still not working.

I even tried `allow_origins=["*"], allow_credentials=False` still nothing.

Another thing to remember here is when I set `allow_origins=[]`, it should not allow any request, even from `localhost`, right? Why is it still allowed from the browser and Postman?

I know this issue looks similar to this [How can I enable CORS in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635346/how-can-i-enable-cors-in-fastapi) , but I have tried every solution in there, but nothing helped.
Here is flutter error when sending request `E/flutter (23012): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused`

My phone browser also says the connection was refused. I dug everywhere, but could not find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Please have a look at the link provided above. Additionally, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804), there is no need for having CORS enabled, unless your API receives cross-origin requests. In that case, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804)

Comment: Oh dear god. Thank you Chris. Both this "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000" and this "if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)" work. However, I still do not understand why was it not working before, I knew that my computer(server) had 2 different IP addresses, 1 for ethernet, and 1 for Wi-Fi. I tried connecting to both a hundred times, unsuccessfully.

Comment: By default FastAPI/Uvicorn runs on `localhost`, and it is thus accessible only from the machine running the server. To make the application available on LAN, one needs to either bind to a machine's local IP address (e.g., `192.168.10.2`) or all interfaces (i.e., `0.0.0.0`), indicating that the server should run on all the machine's IP addresses.

Comment: To expand on what Chris said, it's important to remember that CORS _only applies to requests triggered by a cross-origin operation _- i.e. when a resource makes a request to something on a different origin (for example, a webpage making a JavaScript `fetch` request to a different host). Opening a URL in a browser, calling it from postman or curl or similar isn't a cross origin request, and thus, isn't limited by any CORS information. CORS is a _client side limitation_, and is not enforced server side (since a client could send whatever origin they want).