# FastAPi CORS Headers not coming through

Tags: python, cors, fastapi

I have tried setting up the CORS headers as per the official docs.

But when I test the endpoint locally, the CORS headers don't appear.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import requests
from fastapi import Response
import os


load_dotenv()

key = os.environ["DRF_API_KEY"]

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "https://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

@app.get("/{email}")
async def root(email):
    print("hiya")
    # print("Email is ", email)
    # print("Key is ", key)
    r = requests.get(f'https://api.mydomain.io/retrieve_artist_user/{email}', headers={'Authorization': f'Api-Key {key}'})
    text = r.text
    print(text)
    return Response(content=text, media_type="application/json")
```

I am testing with Postman and keeping an eye on the Headers tab

Answer (score 0):

The CORS headers are not appearing because you are requesting the endpoint directly, not in a cross-origin context.

According to the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=%20cors#use-corsmiddleware) :

> The middleware responds to two particular types of HTTP request...
>
> - CORS preflight requests
> - Simple requests

So you have two ways to test if CORS headers are working correctly:

### Use CORS preflight requests

These requests are typically made by your browser when making cross-origin requests. You can use a simple HTML page with the following script :

```
<script>
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/test").then((Response) => {
        return Response.json()
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
</script>
```

This is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66460861/22268774). You should see a CORS error in your browser's console because the browser has no known Origin and will use *null* as Origin. The CORS error should disappear should you allow all origins in your middleware :

```
origins = ["*"]
```

### Use a simple request with an Origin header

Add an Origin header to your postman request. If this origin matches one allowed in your middleware, you should see an *access-control-allow-origin* header in the response.

### TL;DR

CORS errors are caused by your browser refusing to share an API response with an origin, not by an API refusing to respond (check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).