# React not showing POST response from FastAPI backend application

Tags: python, reactjs, cors, fastapi

I have a simple React Ui which is supposed to get a json file from `localhost:8000/todo` and create the Ui in `localhost:3000`.
This is the desired output:
[image]

However, this is what I get:
[image]

So, the two lines which are "Read a book." and "Cycle around town." are not shown. These two lines are supposed to come from `localhost:8000/todo` which is a `JSON` type information. I feel like I can fetch the data from `localhost:8000/todo`, but I don't know how to show them in `localhost:3000`, which is my output.

Here is the function that I have for this:

```
export default function Todos() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const fetchTodos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/todo")
    const todos = await response.json()
    setTodos(todos.data)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos()
  }, [])
  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={{todos, fetchTodos}}>
      <AddTodo />  
      <Stack spacing={5}>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <b>{todo.item}</b>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

****{todos.item}**** is the part that is supposed to print the items, but it doesn't!

Here is the console log info:
[image]
[image]

Here is the response from `localhost:8000/todo`:
[image]

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to enable [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) in the FastAPI backend. You can configure it in your FastAPI application using the [`CORSMiddleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware).

### Note

> #### [Origin](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#origin)
>
> An origin is the combination of protocol (`http`, `https`), domain
> (`myapp.com`, `localhost`, `localhost.tiangolo.com`), and port (`80`,
> `443`, `8080`).
>
> So, **all these are different origins**:
>
> - `http://localhost`
> - `https://localhost`
> - `http://localhost:8080`
>
> Even if they are all in `localhost`, they use different protocols or
> ports, so, they are different "origins".

### Example

Have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) as well.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```