# How do I fix "blocked by CORS policy" error raised using FastAPI, React and Axios?

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, cors, fastapi

I'm trying to get data using `axios`, but facing the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

I have tried to find a solution, but nowhere I found a proper solution including FastAPI, React and Axios.

Here is my backend:

```
origins = ['https://localhost:3000', 'https://localhost:8080']

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = [origins],
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"]
)


@app.get('/')
def root():
    return {
        "Data" : "Working!"
    }
```

Below is my frontend:

```
const message = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
      let result = res.data;
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    message();
  }, []);
```

The error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Now I'm using it locally adding proxy in `package.json` file. But in production, it doesn't work. However, I need a proper solution for production level without using proxy.

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin-headers will not be added if the backend responds with a 500 internal server error - what is the actual response from the server? Also remember that in production the host probably won't be 'localhost' as the origin address.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804).

Comment: @MatsLindh here it is:

**Request URL: http://localhost:8080/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors**

Comment: @Chris 

I fixed this in 
back-end: `origins = ['http://localhost:3000']` and 
front-end: 
`let res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/");
 let result = res.data;`

still getting the same error **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** and **GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_FAILED 200** this error

Comment: I couldn't find what I missed

Comment: @Chris At first I was working it using proxy to overcome this error but when I hosted in aws for production, the proxy is not working. So now I am running it locally. 
In locally,
response body: **Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier**
status code: 200

Comment: Ok the problem just solved. I just set the origin port in **allow_origin** value directly instead taking it in a variable **origin**.

The code before facing error:
`origins = ['https://localhost:3000', 'https://localhost:8080']

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = [origins],
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"]
)`

The code after:

`app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = ['https://localhost:3000'],
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"]
)`

Comment: This is it. No big changes. I don't know but couldn't get the difference. Anyways it worked and thank you both for response.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `allow_origins=origins`, **without** the brackers `[]` around the `origins` variable.

### Example

```py
origins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://localhost:3000']

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) for more details.