# Unable to access environment variables for api id and key in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

My .env (in root dir):

```
REACT_APP_ID = '123456';
REACT_APP_KEY = 'abcde123';
```

in app.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);


const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_ID}&app_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_KEY}`); //change the elements in the query to match ur ID and KEY + query
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.hits);
    setRecipes(data.hits); 
  }
```

However, it doesn't work. Error thrown in console:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q=paneer&app_id=***;&app_key=***;' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I've tried restarted the server by `npm start` but it doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: have you tried removing ; semicolon at the end. I think that is causing problems.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to ReactJS here. The issue you are facing is about the CORS policy which is related to the networks and headers of the response. you should have something like this in your request header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Also try to use `fetch` with `credentials` included, something like this:

```
fetch(https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_ID}&app_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_KEY}`, {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```