# Sending request from React to FastAPI causes "origin http://localhost:5173 has been blocked by CORS policy" error

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, cors, fastapi

I was making a POST request which sends an image file from my UI to the backend server.

Backend Server:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["http://localhost:5173/"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("../models/1")
class_names = ["Normal", "Tuberculosis"]

def convert_image_to_np_array(bytes):
    # Read bytes as PIL image and convert it to np array
    np_array = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(bytes)))
    return np_array

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict_tuberculosis(file: UploadFile):
    bytes = await file.read()
    np_array = convert_image_to_np_array(bytes)
    batch_image = np.expand_dims(np_array, axis=0)
    resized_batch_image = np.resize(batch_image, (1,256,256,3))
    prediction = model.predict(resized_batch_image)
    label = class_names[np.argmax(prediction)]
    accuracy = np.max(prediction)
    print(accuracy)
    return label
```

Frontend:

```
import React from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  function callPrediction(file) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", file)
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/predict", formData)
    .then(res => setResult(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  ...
```

**Note:** The `file` input from `callPrediction` has the format like this

[image]

When I call the function `callPrediction` to send an image file as an input to the function `predict_tuberculosis` , I got this error popping up

[image]

I did go searching for this but all the solutions I got was just adding CORS to my backend (which I have already done).

I really appreciate any helps! Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **remove the trailing slash** from the origin URL in:

```
http://localhost:5173/
                     ^
```

The origin URL should instead look like this `http://localhost:5173`. Hence:

```py
origins = ["http://localhost:5173"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

For further details, please have a look at the following answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804).

Answer (score -3):

The origins array in your backend server should contain the client url: http://localhost:8000.
so make sure to add it to your origins array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).