# Tried enabling CORS in FastAPI to make requests in my react code. It doesn't work

Tags: python, reactjs, cors, fastapi

For context, I have the following JavaScript code to pull some data from my API via get request

```
useEffect(() => {

        async function getPhones(){
            try{
                const response = await fetch(
                    `https://api.myapi.com/phones?detailed=true&brand=${brand}`
                  );
                  const json = await response.json();
                  setPhones(json)
            } catch(error){
              console.error('Error fetching phones:', error);
          }
        }
        getPhones();
    }, [])
```

Which gives the error of:

> Access to fetch at
> 'http://api.myapi.io/phones/?detailed=true&brand=LG' (redirected from
> 'https://api.myapi.io/phones?detailed=true&brand=LG') from origin
> 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I then tried following the FastAPI docs and previous questions on Atack Overflow to enable the following:

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

I even tried omitting the `allowed_methods` as stated on some stack overflows but none of that works.

I also noticed that in my useEffect request if I use the URL `https://api.myapi.com/phones` there is no CORS error which I do not know why

Comment: so the cors error is gone when you request without searchParams?

Comment: Yes @CarlosDanielVilaseca

Comment: then is very likely not to be a cors error but other error in the code, browsers tend to give those false positives wich can be very missleading, i suggest you check your logs

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032415/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804)

Comment: @CarlosDanielVilaseca Browsers don't report false-positive CORS errors.

Comment: @CarlosDanielVilaseca It cant be a false positive because I make the same url request in my browser and the correct JSON response is displayed

Comment: Direct requests isn't subject to CORS limitations. Look at the actual response coming from the server (when made from your javascript) in your network tools and whether that is the response you're expecting. CORS headers _are not added_ when the request ends in an error (i.e. something other than 200/300).

Comment: @Chris I already did everything mentioned in those posts however they dont work